# Как в jade перенести тег на новую строку?

Tags: jade

Всем привет.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в jade перенести тег на новую строку.

Вот jade:

```
menu
    = '\n'
    a.menu__item(href="#") Ссылка-1
    = '\n'
    a.menu__item(href="#") Ссылка-2
    = '\n'
    a.menu__item(href="#") Ссылка-3
```

На выходе получаем корявый html без индентации:

```
            <div class="menu">
<a href="#" class="menu__item">Ссылка-1</a>
<a href="#" class="menu__item">Ссылка-2</a>
<a href="#" class="menu__item">Ссылка-3</a>
            </div>
```

Пробовал так писать, не компилирует:

```
menu
    | a.menu__item(href="#") Ссылка-1
    | a.menu__item(href="#") Ссылка-2
    | a.menu__item(href="#") Ссылка-3
```

Answer (score 1):

В компиляторе который вы используете нужно выставить опцию pretty: true, по умолчанию она false.

Например, gulp task

```
gulp.task('pug', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/*.pug')
    .pipe(pug({
      pretty: true
   }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dev'));
});
```

После этого не нужно никаких специальных символов, делайте обычный отступ

```
.menu
  a.menu__item(href="#") Ссылка-1
  a.menu__item(href="#") Ссылка-2
  a.menu__item(href="#") Ссылка-3
```

[Jade (Pug) API Reference](https://pugjs.org/api/reference.html)

Comment: Тогда html (тег а) в одну строку.

Comment: @jsp Дополнил ответ

Comment: использую prepros, в настройках отметил [ссылка](https://yadi.sk/i/ZNp8qzMuxxiK3) , результата нет

Comment: prepros не использовал, не могу с ним помочь

Comment: @jsp, в препросе есть опция, которая так и называется (вроде бы) "pretty", поищи получше в настройках.

Answer (score 1):

Просто ставишь двойной строчный плайн текст (в которых пишешь пробелы), и всё (:

```
body
  .divchik
  | 
  | 
  .divchikNaNovoyStroke
```

Учти, что вложенность (нестинг) для комментов действует по всем правилам jade (pug, если угодно) для тегов.